# Add explicit write access to the other user when creating a room with them

Tags: feature-request, chat

When creating a room with someone, chat grants you (the room creator) automatic ownership. I think it would make great sense to also grant explicit write permissions to the user I've opened a room with as well.

The main usecase is when I want a quiet conversation with someone, and want to place the room under gallery or private (in the case of a mod), in that case, today, I need to also add the user to the explicit write (or owner) list myself, in addition to setting the room's permission level.

I think it would be more intuitive and save a few clicks/seconds.

Comment: Agree about private room as it's kind of silly to start a room where the other user can't even talk. About gallery for ordinary users, well, that's rare enough that I'm not sure it's really important.